# Prove that $O((N+1)\log(N+1)) \approx O(N\log N)$

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

I am trying to prove that $O((N+1)\log(N+1)) \approx O(N\log N)$. I have the following:

Assume that $N \geq 1$. Then:
\begin{align}
N+1 &\leq N + N \leq 2N \\
\log(N+1) &\leq \log(2N) = \log 2 + \log N \\
\log(N+1) - \log2 &\leq \log N
\end{align}
However, I am not exactly sure how to continue from here. What techniques could I use to demonstrate that $O((N+1)\log(N+1)) \approx O(N\log N)$? I am thinking that one way to prove this is to show that $N\log N$ can be larger than $(N+1)\log(N+1)$ under certain circumstances.
Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: $\log{2} < \log{N}$ when $N>2$ so $(N+1)\log(N+1) < 4N\log{N}$ for $N>2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, show that $N^2>N+1$ for $N$ big enough (how big?) and second, $2N>N+1$ for $N$ big enough (this, you have already). This implies, that for any constant $c_1\in \mathbb R_+$, and for $N$ big enough

\begin{align}c_1(N+1)\log {(N+1)}\le c_12N\log{N^2}=c_14N\log{N}=\mathcal O(N\log{N})\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If we have some:
$$f(n)=n\log(n)$$
and:
$$f(n+1)=(n+1)\log(n+1)$$
we can see that when $n\to\infty$ the value of $1$ compared to $n$ is small enough that:
$$O(n)=O(n+1)$$
and we can continue this to say that:
$$O[f(n)]=O[f(n+1)]$$
Hence:
$$O[n\log(n)]=O[(n+1)\log(n+1)]$$